# How do I record/playback vinyl audio in a daw?

Tags: midi, daw, vinyl

My vinyl player has a midi port that allows you to record the vinyl using software like Audacity.

I was wandering if it was possible to have these audio signals sent directly to my DAW (Bitwig) through the midi cable (via qJack). I don’t want the audio signals being sent through the RCA because I only have 1 aux port which I am reserving for the output.

The vinyl doesn’t show up in Bitwig’s audio device and to be honest I wasn’t even aware that MIDI could send signals in the form of audio waves.

Comment: It would help if we knew the exact make & model of your turntable & what input/output options you have on the computer. Answers can then be tweaked accordingly.

Comment: Without knowing the model of your vinyl player we can only offer guesses …

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to be Midi, though it's likely to be one of the same family of DIN plugs. These used to be popular on hifi & audio gear, though they're not used much these days. Even if it's the same 5-pin as used for Midi, it's still probably analog audio.

Look at [DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector) to identify the type, then you'll need an adapter to break it out to something you can use on the computer. You will also need to correctly identify the pinout.

Note that you will very likely have to create an RIAA curve in software if you don't go through a proper phono pre-amp first (See [RIAA equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIAA_equalization)). Vinyl records are not cut with a 'flat' EQ, they have a specific curve to lessen the amount of bass that must be cut, to prevent the needle skipping. This needs to be reversed for playback, or it will sound thin & scratchy.

For the plug pinout, see this for some clues - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/125267/can-anyone-help-me-identify-this-old-audio-cable

Answer (score 0):

> I wasn’t even aware that MIDI could send signals in the form of audio waves.

Neither was I. MIDI  (at its simplest) carries digital note information, not digitised audio.

MIDI does use [DIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector) connectors, which can also be used, separately, for analog audio signals.

[image: DIN plug]

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector)

It's this what you have? Can you link to a manual for your player? If you have an analog output you'll need a suitable cable to connect to the line input on your PC or an external USB soundcard/audio interface if you've already used the analog line in on your DAW.